# How do I disable microsoft office updates?

Tags: upgrade, office365, microsoft-office-2007

I have a licensed copy of office 2007, but after installing it on my new laptop I'm apparently forced to update excel (and, I imagine, the rest of office) to office 365.

I don't want to. I want to use the software I already paid for and am familar with.

Am I hosed?

Note: searches only returned results for disabling notifications.

Note: Yes, new laptop, Windows 10. I assume there's a promotional Office365 install - I've never checked for this. I shall attempt a full Office365 uninstall and then install 2007 again, thanks!

Comment: Windows 10?????

Comment: Do you have Office 365 installed as a promotional program, common with new computers?

Comment: Sounds like you were offered to upgrade to Office 365 and you accepted that offer, because while it is out of support, you absolutely can still use it.  Use the tool to uninstall Office completely and then reinstall Office 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8) and download Office uninstall tool from the option 2 and remove Office 365 from PC.

Then try to install Office 2007: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/install-office-2007-88a8e329-3335-4f82-abb2-ecea3e319657

Comment: Thank you so much, it is now working like a charm!